# Creating a static class to open a new window in Java FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am working on a project where there's a lot of windows being opened and closed and would like to create a static class which only takes in a few parameters and then does the rest.

The problem is that "controller" will need to be different types of declaration, depending on what controller is needed. For instance; `FXMLControllerAdd` or `FXMLControllerHome`.

I tried to pass the type to the method with a parameter. That did not work, neither did using var as declaration (it's coded in Java11) because then i got a "cannot find symbol"-error for initData() on the next line.

```
public static void nySide(Class c, String controllerPath, Dataset dataset, String tittel, Window window) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(c.getResource(controllerPath));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        //THIS IS WHERE TO PROBLEM IS
        FXMLControllerAdd controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initData(dataset);

        //This line gets the Stage information
        Stage st = new Stage();
        st.setTitle(tittel);
        st.setScene(new Scene(root));

        st.show();

        Stage stage = (Stage) window;
        stage.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also; does it exists another way which requires less parameters?

Comment: Does `FXMLControllerAdd` have an `initData(Dataset)` method visible to this utility class? And if multiple controller types can be instantiated and used here, have them implement a common interface.

Comment: making an interface and implementing that interface did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to Slaw. Making an interface E.g (FXMLInitData) and implementing that in every FXMLController.java and declaring controller as that interface did the trick.

Interface:

```
public interface FXMLInitData {

    public void initData(Dataset dataset);

}
```

Method:

```
public static void nySide(Class c, String controllerPath, Dataset dataset, String tittel, Window window){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(c.getResource(controllerPath));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        FXMLInitData controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initData(dataset);

        //This line gets the Stage information
        Stage st = new Stage();
        st.setTitle(tittel);
        st.setScene(new Scene(root));

        st.show();

        Stage stage = (Stage) window;
        stage.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class FXMLControllerHome implements Initializable, FXMLInitData{
    @Override
    public void initData(Dataset dataset){

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try letting every controller extend or implement a parent Controller-class. Make the parent Controller a parameter, and pass the child-controller as a parameter when calling the method instead of `String controllerPath`.

Comment: It worked using an interface (see my answer), but didn't quite understand your solution. Would it require less peramaters than the my solution with interface or is it basically the same?

Comment: It would basically be the same and was meant as a quick-fix for your problem. Since you want to use the same setup for all windows you can't really lessen the number of parameters easily